# Pact Broker pod won't start on OpenShift: bundler: failed to load command: puma `Integer': invalid value for Integer

Tags: openshift, nexus, puma, pact-broker

I've installed pactfoundation/pact-broker image from our nexus on OpenShift. The pod stays in CrashLoopBackOff status with this error in the pod log:

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma)
/pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/dsl.rb:266:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "tcp://172.30.196.225:8080" (ArgumentError)
      bind URI::Generic.build(scheme: 'tcp', host: host, port: Integer(port)).to_s
                                                                       ^^^^
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/dsl.rb:266:in `port'
    from config/puma.rb:3:in `_load_from'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/dsl.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/dsl.rb:87:in `_load_from'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/configuration.rb:219:in `block in load'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/configuration.rb:219:in `each'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/configuration.rb:219:in `load'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/launcher.rb:60:in `initialize'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/cli.rb:72:in `new'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/lib/puma/cli.rb:72:in `initialize'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/bin/puma:8:in `new'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.7/bin/puma:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `load'
    from /pact_broker/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
```

Looks like there is a problem with puma in the image or our nexus. Any comments are highly appreciated.